# Elasticsearch endpoint to test users without any roles

Tags: elasticsearch, roles

I just defined the user in Elasticsearch (through [Kibana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibana) UI) and want to test the user can reach and authorize in Elastic.

What endpoint can I use for testing a user is known to Elastic from the user's perspective? (no high privileges administrator API)

All I tried required some kind of roles, and requests looked like:

```
curl --basic --user user:pass https://evil.com:9200/_cat/indices
```

***Update***: With `curl -v`, I see 401 / 403 to differentiate if the password is correct. I'd like to have some endpoint that returns 200 for the correct password and 401 for incorrect or non existing user...

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding right, you just want to check if Kibana is opening only with the defined username and password or not.

So you can just hit:

```
https://your_ip or kibana_ip_whichever_given:5601

or

http://your_ip or kibana_ip_whichever_given:5601
```

If you have used *xpack.security* in it, then try *https*. Otherwise, try it with *http*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the X-Pack API to test if the user is known to the Elasticsearch cluster, without requiring high privileges. The API is available at the endpoint `/_xpack/security/user/<username>` and will return a 200 status code if the user is known and an error code (e.g. 401 or 403) if the user is not known or not authorized.

for more... https://discuss.elastic.co/t/216937